# Prolog menu prompt doesn't print properly

Tags: prolog

I made a menu that compile without error, but has a strange behavior. It's supposed to ask three time for different input, but it only show 2 different prompt.

The goal of the number 1 choice of the menu is to read from the user input the `name` , the `price`  and the `year`  of the car, and than adding it to the database.

Here is the code:

```
menu :- write('-- Menu --'),nl, write('0. Quit'), nl, write('1. Add a car'), nl,  read(X), pick(X).
pick(0) :- write('The end.'),nl.
pick(1) :-
write("Name:"), 
read_line(N),nl,
write("Price :"),
read_line(P),nl,
write("Year :"),
read_line(Y),nl,
assertz(car(N,P,Y)),
menu.

:- dynamic car/3.
car(blue1,2000, 2012 ). 
car(blue2,1000, 2006).
car(red1,2000, 2010).

read_line(String) :-
    current_input(Input),
    read_string(Input, "\n", "\r", _, String).
```

What is wrong with this code? I tried to decompose the predicate and only use `read_string` , but I get the same result.

EDIT: While the accepted answer solved my first issue, I still have issues with my program.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the stuff given to write/1 in quotes:

```
write('Price :')
```

or

```
write("Price :")
```

so that it is interpreted as a "element of text".

The "element of text" can then be mapped to a Prolog 'atom' or maybe, in SWI-Prolog, an SWI-Prolog 'string'.

If the text only contains alphanumerics and begins with a lowercase letter, there is no need to quote it to get a Prolog atom directly.

```
?- atom('foo').
true.

?- atom(foo).
true.

?- atom('foo bar baz').
true.

?- atom(foo bar baz).
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: atom(foo
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR:  bar baz) .
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution if anyone is having a similar issue. You need to add `,nl` after the `write(X)` for it to print properly.